# stoping JBOSS via Ant task

Tags: java, ant, jboss

Im trying those targets. And all of them throws exception as below. 
Any idea what is wrong?

Ant targets:

```
<target name="serverOFF2">
<sequential>
<java dir="${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf" classname="org.jboss.Shutdown" fork="false">
<arg line="localhost 8080"/>
<classpath>
<pathelement path="${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/shutdown.jar"/>
</classpath>
</java>
</sequential>
</target>

<target name="serverOFF3">
<exec executable="${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/shutdown.bat" spawn="false">
<arg line="-S" />
</exec>
</target>

<target name="serverOFF4">
<exec dir="${JBOSS_HOME}/bin" executable="cmd.exe"
os="Windows 2000,Windows XP">
<arg line="/c shutdown.bat -S"/>
<env key="NOPAUSE" value="true"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

Exception:
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: PC45577

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting your JBoss server with the "jboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0" in your startup batch file? If not, then the server will only listen locally and will not be reachable.

So you would start the server up by doing:

```
run.bat -b192.168.3.100 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

EDIT: From my later comment

Also check that your firewall is not blocking the JNDI Port TCP 1099. Try to connect to the port using telnet or netcat:

```
telnet 192.168.3.100 1099
nc -vv 192.168.3.100 1099
```

Comment: Yes, I Am. Besides JBOSS is installed at the same PC from which I'm runing ant task.

Comment: How about when you specify the RMI server IP like so:

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.3.100

Comment: Hmm, did you change your JNDI port from the default 1099? If not, can you reach it by trying to connect to it using "telnet localhost 1099" I presume you switched off or configured the firewall to allow access to these ports?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Firewall was blocking port 1099. Thanks for help.